# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Requires moderation'

Tags: python, django

In past I've resolve this problem couple of times and in my practice this was only related to date time field issues. Currently I am not able to determine 
the reason for this error at all and this is really frustrating. I am posting the complete model with its view and exact functions where traceback points 
out the error in code. However I've also added date time fields of the Product model which is related by a ForeignKey field at end of post which I believe
may not be relevant but perhaps it might help. A little explanation about the issue would be a great help as well. Please advise.

ProductReview model:

```
class ProductReview(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        'catalogue.Product', related_name='reviews', null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    SCORE_CHOICES = tuple([(x, x) for x in range(0, 6)])
    score = models.SmallIntegerField(_("Score"), choices=SCORE_CHOICES)
    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=pgettext_lazy(u"Product review title", u"Title"),
        max_length=255, validators=[validators.non_whitespace])
    body = models.TextField(_("Body"))
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='reviews', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(
        pgettext_lazy(u"Anonymous reviewer name", u"Name"),
        max_length=255, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), blank=True)
    homepage = models.URLField(_("URL"), blank=True)
    FOR_MODERATION, APPROVED, REJECTED = 0, 1, 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (FOR_MODERATION, _("Requires moderation")),
        (APPROVED, _("Approved")),
        (REJECTED, _("Rejected")),
    )
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(
        _("Status"), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="Requires moderation")
    total_votes = models.IntegerField(
        _("Total Votes"), default=0)  # upvotes + down votes
    delta_votes = models.IntegerField(
        _("Delta Votes"), default=0, db_index=True)  # upvotes - down votes
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = ProductReviewQuerySet.as_manager()
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'reviews'
        ordering = ['-delta_votes', 'id']
        unique_together = (('product', 'user'),)
        verbose_name = _('Product review')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Product reviews')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductReview, self).save(*args, **kwargs) #This line shows error
        self.product.update_rating()
```

View:

```
class CreateProductReview(CreateView):
    template_name = "catalogue/reviews/review_form.html"
    model = ProductReview
    product_model = Product
    form_class = ProductReviewForm
    view_signal = review_added

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.product = get_object_or_404(
            self.product_model, pk=kwargs['product_pk'])

        if not self.product.is_review_permitted(request.user):
            if self.product.has_review_by(request.user):
                message = _("You have already reviewed this product!")
            else:
                message = _("You can't leave a review for this product.")
            messages.warning(self.request, message)
            return redirect(self.product.get_absolute_url())

        return super(CreateProductReview, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In view form_valid function:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(CreateProductReview, self).form_valid(form)
        self.send_signal(self.request, response, self.object)
        return response
```

Related model called in Review includes few date fields:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    .....#fields intentionally not posted to keep question summarized on stackoverflow
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_("Date created"), auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Date updated"), auto_now=True, db_index=True)
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\AliKhan\amazonclone\market\catalogue\reviews\views.py" in dispatch
  40.             request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AliKhan\amazonclone\market\catalogue\reviews\views.py" in form_valid
  54.         response = super(CreateProductReview, self).form_valid(form)
File "C:\Users\AliKhan\amazonclone\market\catalogue\reviews\models.py" in save
  108.         super(ProductReview, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
Exception Type: ValueError at /catalogue/new-product_4/reviews/add/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Requires moderation'
```

Comment: The error is clear you can't convert the string `'Requires moderation'` to an int, have you tried to debug this or check your casting attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Requires moderation'` only relates to the human readable string for your given choice.  Instead you need to use the integer that represents that choice for your default

```
models.SmallIntegerField(_("Status"), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=FOR_MODERATION)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `status` field is a `SmallIntegerField` with a default value of the *string* "Requires Moderation". You can't put such a string in a numeric field.

The trick to finding this is to find where `Requires Moderation` appears in your code.

Comment: This way it works perfectly fine in Django-Oscar an ecommerce site where I copied review model for practice and I tried to find any dependencies that may helped to alter the behavior but it works fine for them should work for me also. Shouldn't it?